# Pasar un campo a la bd según el template que uso DJANGO

Tags: base-de-datos, django

Hola buenas a tod@s tengo un problema, es el siguiente: yo tengo un fichador (un template de entrada y otro de salida) pues cuando el usuario me ponga el codigo en el template de entrada se envía se pasa ese codigo y la fecha, pero quiero que según sea entrada o salida se pase a BD, es decir si es el template de entrar que el tipo ponga entrada en BD.

Código:

```
class fichador_entrada(CreateViewEntrada):
    model = fichador
    fields = ['Codigo']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entrada'] = fichador.objects.all()
        return context

class fichador_salida(CreateViewSalida):
    model = fichador
    fields = ['Codigo']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['salida'] = fichador.objects.all()
        return context
<!-- HTML -->
 <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'entrada' %}">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Entrada</span>
                </a>
            </li>

               <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'salida' %}">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Salida</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

[image: Dependiendo del template que pase el tipo entrada o salida]
[image: Fichando en el template de entrada quiero que ahi salga "Entrada"]

Comment: Si tienes definido el campo en el modelo (que de hecho puede ser Boolean o Choices), bastaría con una única vista, solo que con el parámetro (que podrías pasar por URL) de si es fichar entrada o fichar salida.

Comment: Si lo hago como Choices como hago lo de pasar el parametro por url ? gracias

Comment: En la url del fichador incluyes el parámetro: `path('<str:tipo>/', FichadorView)` y en la vista puedes utilizar directamente el parámetro `tipo` para mostrar el formulario correspondiente (que supongo es el mismo pero con el campo `tipo` predefinido.